# Cursor should be at the center of the image on .click()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making this little exemple where I'm trying to center an image to the cursor, basically, when you click, the cursor should be at the center of the image.
Since I'm a beginner, I don't really see how I could achieve that.
Maybe it's by using something like `$(".theImg").height` but I think I'm doing this wrong since it doesn't work. Maybe I have to use a `transform`...

```js
$(document.body).click(function(event) {
        x = event.pageX;
        y = event.pageY;
        console.log(x +", "+ y);
        console.log(('theImg').height);

        $(".paysage") .css({'position' : 'absolute', 'top': y, 'left' : x})
                      .prepend($('<img>',{  class:'theImg',
                                            src:'https://www.30millionsdamis.fr/uploads/pics/conseils-erreurs-chat-1171.jpg'})) 
        $(".theImg").prev().remove();       
              
});
```

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

.theImg{
  width :20em;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "paysage"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) css property on `img`

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

```js
$(document.body).click(function(event) {
  x = event.pageX;
  y = event.pageY;
  console.log(x + ", " + y);
  console.log(('theImg').height);

  $(".paysage").css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'top': y,
      'left': x
    })
    .prepend($('<img>', {
      class: 'theImg',
      src: 'https://www.30millionsdamis.fr/uploads/pics/conseils-erreurs-chat-1171.jpg'
    }))

  $(".theImg").prev().remove();
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

.theImg {
  width: 20em;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="paysage"></div>
```

Comment: It was this simple haha.
Thanks for the help and also for reformating my code!

Answer (score 1):

Add this selector with rule to your css:

```
.paysage {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Was it necessary?

```js
$(document.body).click(function(event) {
        x = event.pageX;
        y = event.pageY;
        console.log(x +", "+ y);
        console.log(('theImg').height);

        $(".paysage") .css({'position' : 'absolute', 'top': y, 'left' : x})
                      .prepend($('<img>',{  class:'theImg',
                                            src:'https://www.30millionsdamis.fr/uploads/pics/conseils-erreurs-chat-1171.jpg'})) 
        $(".theImg").prev().remove();       
              
});
```

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

.theImg{
  width :20em;
  height: auto;
}

.paysage {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "paysage"> </div>
```

Comment: Hi Sergey,
thanks for the help, it was very simple !

Comment: Yes, sometimes easy questions seem difficult at first glance :) I was glad to help!